# I am trying to convert .pb file to .mlmodel file. I am getting an error "Tensorflow graph does not contain a tensor with this name"

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, coreml, mlmodel

I tried using tfcoreml and the error is :

Loading the TF graph...

2018-12-05 11:16:50.591360: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA

Graph Loaded.
Collecting all the 'Const' ops from the graph, by running it....
Done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "converter.py", line 4, in 
    output_feature_names = ['softmax:0'])
  File "/root/tensorflow-for-poets-2/tf_files/tf-coreml/tfcoreml/_tf_coreml_converter.py", line 586, in convert
    custom_conversion_functions=custom_conversion_functions)
  File "/root/tensorflow-for-poets-2/tf_files/tf-coreml/tfcoreml/_tf_coreml_converter.py", line 272, in _convert_pb_to_mlmodel
    raise ValueError("output name: {}, was provided, but the Tensorflow graph does not contain a tensor with this name.".format(given_out_name))
ValueError: output name: softmax:0, was provided, but the Tensorflow graph does not contain a tensor with this name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `tfcoreml.convert()` you need to supply the name of the tensor with the model's output. You supplied `"softmax:0"`, probably because you saw that in a tutorial somewhere. But apparently this is not the name of the output from your own TensorFlow graph.

You can use a tool called [Netron](https://github.com/lutzroeder/Netron/) to inspect your graph to see what the name of the output tensor is.

Comment: I changed my tensor name and it worked. Thanks a lot @Matthijs Hollemans